# JDK problems - Unable to load class files

Tags: windows-xp, java, command-prompt, .class-file

Ok, so. I ordered a book on Java (Sams teach yourself java in 21 days) a week ago, and it came in just yesterday. I am working on the first example code, and I keep getting this error when I try to compile the main code:

> C:\VolcanoApplication.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
>
> VolcanoRobot dante = new VolcanoRobot();
>
> ^
>
> symbol: class VolcanoRobot
>
> location: class VolcanoApplication
>
> C:\VolcanoApplication.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
>
> VolcanoRobot dante = new VolcanoRobot();
>
> ```
>                      ^
> ```
>
> symbol: class VolcanoRobot
>
> location: class VolcanoApplication

And the main code Im trying to compile is:

```
public class VolcanoApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] arguments)
    {
        VolcanoRobot dante = new VolcanoRobot();
        dante.status = "exploring";
        dante.speed = 2;
        dante.temperature = 510;

        dante.showAttributes();
        System.out.println("Increasting speed to 3.");
        dante.speed = 3;
        dante.showAttributes();
        System.out.println("Changing temperature to 670.");
        dante.temperature = 670;
        dante.showAttributes();
        System.out.println("Checking the temperature.");
        dante.checkTemperature();
        dante.showAttributes();
    }
}
```

and the VolcanoRobot.java file:

```
public class VolcanoRobot
{
    String status;
    int speed;
    float temperature;

    void checkTemperature()
    {
        if(temperature > 660)
        {
            status = "returning home";
            speed = 5;
        }
    }

    void showAttributes()
    {
        System.out.println("Status: " + status);
        System.out.println("Speed: " + speed);
        System.out.println("Temperature: " + temperature);
    }
}
```

I am unable to get javac to run anywhere in command prompt (I'm running xp) so I navigate to where my javac.exe is (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin) and compile VolcanoApplication from there (VolcanoApplication is found on the root of C:)

When I just type Java anywhere I get the menu, but not javac. I declared the path and classpath variables, and yet it doesn't work. any suggestions?

Comment: @ Alex St-Laurent: Please install an IDE and focus on real issues.

Comment: @ Alex St-Laurent: you mentioned that you started on the book. My feedback is to use an IDE so   you can focus on the actual problems.. Try intelliJ : http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/.  or eclipse.

Comment: Ok, but I have found a workaround, and define "real Problem", because a problem to me is any kind of hold back, and not being able to import class files is a hold back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to make `javac` work from any directory by going into the environment variables and changing your `PATH` so it includes `C:\Program Files\jdk1.7.0_03\bin`.

Once you've done that, in a command prompt typing `javac` anywhere should work.

The reason `javac` isn't finding the `VolcanoRobot.java` file is that it's not in the path that `javac` searches for source files. By default, that path includes the current directory, so if you `cd` to the directory containing `VolcanoApplication.java` and `VolcanoRobot.java`, then

```
javac VolcanoRobot.java VolcanoApplication.java
```

...should do it. If it doesn't, add `-cp .`:

```
javac -cp . VolcanoRobot.java VolcanoApplication.java
```

You should then be able to run it via

```
java VolcanoApplication
```

...or

```
java -cp . VolcanoApplication
```

---

**Update**: Since my main workstation is Linux-based, I hadn't done this under Windows 7 (used to do it all the time with Windows XP) and so I got to wondering whether there was something special about it. Doesn't look like there is. I installed the JDK on my Windows 7 box and didn't have any trouble using it. Here's exactly what I did:

1. Opened a command prompt and typed `javac` and pressed Enter, just to make sure I didn't have one installed I didn't remember. I got the usual "...is not recognized as an internal or external command" error.
2. Downloaded the JDK installer from Oracle.
3. Ran it, letting it install to its default location.
4. Opened the Control Panel.
5. Typed "environ" into the search box (because I'm lazy and don't bother to keep track of where they've moved it to this week).
6. Clicked the "Edit system environment variables" choice and clicked Yes on the admin permissions pop-up question. This opened a "System Properties" dialog with the "Advanced" tab open.
7. Clicked the "Environment Variables..." button on that tab.
8. In the "System variables" box at the bottom, scrolled down to `Path`.
9. With that highlighted, clicked the "Edit..." button, which opened the "Edit System Variable" box.
10. In Windows Explorer, navigated to the JDK's `bin` directory, which was at `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin`.
11. Clicked in the address bar, selected all, and copied that path to the clipboard.
12. Back in the "Edit System Variable" box, I put the cursor at the end of the path, typed a semicolon (`;`) (note: not a colon, and with no spaces around it), and then pasted the path from the clipboard.
13. Clicked the OK button on that box, the OK button on the "Environment Variables" box, and the OK button on the "System Properties" box.
14. Opened a new commmand prompt.
15. Typed `javac` and pressed Enter. I got the `javac` help listing.
16. Created the two volcano source files and put them in a directory (in my case, `C:\tmp\j`).
17. Changed into that directory.
18. Typed:

    ```
     javac VolcanoRobot.java VolcanoApplication.java
    ```

    ...and pressed Enter. I got no errors.
19. Typed:

    ```
    java VolcanoApplication
    ```

    ...and pressed Enter. It worked just fine, I got the output I'd expect from looking at the source files.

So there's no problem doing this on Windows 7. Perhaps what I did above will be helpful to you.

Comment: I have declared where javac is in the path variable, and i have also declared the tools.jar under classpath, and yet, it doesn't work.

Comment: @AlexSt-Laurent: I don't know what to tell you. If you've put the correct path to `javac` in the `PATH` env variable and restarted your command prompt (you said you rebooted, which counts), then Windows **will** find `javac` using that path. If it doesn't, it means there's a problem with the path you've added to `PATH`. In your command prompt, type `path` and press enter. If you don't see the path to `javac`, then you haven't added it correctly. If you think you see the path to `javac`, look **very closely** to see where the typo is (there is one, either in the path or the `;` before it).

Comment: I have navigated to where javac is found in windows explorer, copied and pasted the path into the path variable. (it shows up perfectly in CMD) Thanks for trying to help, but i think the problem is unfixable. i am just putting the .java files straight where javac is found, and that seems to work fine.

Comment: @AlexSt-Laurent: The problem is fixable. I'm sorry I can't seem to help you fix it from here, but I'm quite sure there's absolutely nothing special about doing this under Windows (Home edition or otherwise). I've just installed the JDK on my Windows 7 box to prove it to myself, see the edited answer. Good luck,

Comment: I feel like a complete idiot. my problem was a space between the semicolon and the directory in the path variable. DUH. well, thanks! your edit fixed my problem. Greatly appreciate it!

Comment: @AlexSt-Laurent: That's great!! Wow, Windows is amazingly stupid about the `path`, isn't it? Now that you've got it working from the command line, I do recommend finding an IDE, they make life a lot easier. Even though it's not free, I strongly recommend IntelliJ IDEA from JetBrains. There's a reason lots of us pay for it even though Eclipse and NetBeans are free. :-)

Comment: Thanks! I sure will look into that!

Answer (score 1):

If the **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin** folder is entered into your system path environment variable, you might need to reopen **cmd.exe**, as it will not load these environment variables on the fly.

You then need to run javac from the root of your application.

Comment: I have tried all of that, even rebooting, if it helps, I have service pack 3 on XP

Comment: @AlexSt-Laurent: If you've rebooted and it's still not finding `javac`, then you haven't succeeded in putting the relevant path in your `PATH` variable and you need to go back and recheck.

Comment: Then it must be incorrect in your Path variable. It's worth a double check. Under System Properties > Environment Variables, and it's called 'Path' (not pathtext or classpath). The entries must be separated with a semicolon. Sorry if that's all obvious, but this is where the problem is, and you gotta double check it :)

Comment: Here is a link about [setting environment variables on Windows XP](http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/environment.htm)

Comment: I have done all that several times before, I just don't know what's wrong! I have heard that Home Edition is different in some ways (I forgot to mention i am running XP Home Edition) and that might be hindering it to work.

Comment: Perhaps try adding a trailing '\' ?

Comment: I have an idea, what about I put the .java source file in the same folder as the javac.exe file?

Comment: That would work, but is hardly a solution...have you tried to view what value of the Path environment variable cmd.exe is using? Just enter "set" at the prompt.

Comment: T.J. Crowder already suggested that, but thanks. I have put the two files into where javac is found, and it works fine.

Comment: While we are here, your VolcanoRobot class needs a constructor.

Comment: I was referring to the fact that he is creating an object and then setting what seem to be default field values. Not to the fact that code was in any way invalid.

Comment: What is a constructor? (I am new to Java since yesterday)